# Как сделать кнопку адаптивной?

Tags: html, css

Не влезает до конца контент

[пример на Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j76oxhnf/)

```css
.button_name {
  position: absolute;
  top: 115px;
  right: 0;
  line-height: 56px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  min-width: 162px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-family: Interface-bold, sans-serif;
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/W94Hceq.png) no-repeat;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.button_name::before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  top: 50%;
  right: 19px;
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/vrHcNuM.png) no-repeat;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -50%, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, -50%, 0);
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="button button_name">Deposit 100500</a>
```

Comment: ну можно уменьшить шрифт или добавить ширину

Comment: Если откровенно, не совсем понятно, что значит кнопку адаптивно...

Comment: "Резиновую" под количество текста

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проще фон кнопки задать через `gradient`, а так вот подправленный ваш код:

```css
.button_name {
  position: absolute;
  top: 115px;
  right: 0;
  line-height: 56px;
  
  //padding-left: 25px;
  padding: 0 50px 0 25px; // От меня
  
  min-width: 162px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-family: Interface-bold, sans-serif;

  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/W94Hceq.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%; // От меня

  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.button_name::before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  top: 50%;
  right: 19px;
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/vrHcNuM.png) no-repeat;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -50%, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, -50%, 0);
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="button button_name">Deposit 100500</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я понял вопрос.

```css
.button_name {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 50%;
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-family: Interface-bold, sans-serif;
    background: url(https://i.imgur.com/W94Hceq.png) no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    }
.button_name::before {
    content: url(https://i.imgur.com/vrHcNuM.png);
    padding: 0 5px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="button button_name">Deposit 1005000000000</a>
```

Comment: Только хотел написать, `поиграй с  padding-ом`

Comment: Я подумал, что ::before не совсем правильно используется. В общем, как одно из решений имеет право на жизнь)

Comment: согласен. должен быть контейнер... два блока внутри... более грамотно более адаптивно... я бы так реализовал...

Comment: Всегда приятно получить похвалу от мэтров ;-). С благодарностью.